# OTP application:load doesn't load a new compiled code

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I've compiled my app, then load it:

```
application:load(my_app).
application:start(my_app).
```

Then unload:

```
application:stop(m_app).
application:unload(my_app).
```

Then recompile applcation by running build script from an other shell, check that there new files exists in `ebin`. Then try to start my app again:

```
application:load(my_app).
application:start(my_app).
```

And I've got the old code running.

How to renew my application code without quiting and restarting erlang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is cached. 
From shell you can type:

```
l(<name_of_changed_module>).
```

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/c.html#l-1